# How to set inputText to required without affecting output label in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I set an inputText to required, the the outputLabel I have associated with the inputText gets an asterisk added to it automatically. How do I prevent the asterisk from appearing?

```
<p:outputLabel value="Target Species" for="idInputText" />  
<p:inputText id="idInputText" required="true" value="#{controller.string}"/>
```

I am using PrimeFaces 4.0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend using the plain JSF `<h:ouputLabel… />`

```
<h:outputLabel value="Target Species" for="idInputText" />  
<p:inputText id="idInputText" required="true" value="#{controller.string}"/>
```

This removes the asterisk but keeps the label correctly associated with the input element. This is important for accessibility.

Comment: thanks i think this is the best solution because it preserves accessibility

Comment: This changes the styling of the label component and the `for` attribute may not link to the `inputText` on some versions and configurations even though it may looks like it's linking from the source code. You can test by clicking on the label to check if the input receives focus. The best solution is to add `indicateRequired="false"` to `p:outputLabel` as shown at the [Jasper de Vries answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37142079/804976)

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if this also works for 4, but it does for PrimeFaces 5.3: simply add `indicateRequired="false"`. So:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Target Species"
               for="idInputText"
               indicateRequired="false"/>  
<p:inputText id="idInputText"
             required="true"
             value="#{controller.string}"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use css to hide the `asterisk`:

```
.ui-outputlabel-rfi { display: none; }
```

Then the label will still be associated with the input, and you can still use a Label Provider if you like:

http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/label-provider-for-jsf-input-components/

Answer (score -1):

```
indicateRequired="true"
```

For example:

```
<p:inputText value="#{bean.firstName}" indicateRequired="true" required="true" requiredMessage="Name is required"/>
```

Comment: If you don't want it to show, set indicateRequired to false

Comment: `indicateRequired="false"` should be added to `<p:outputLabel>` and not to `<p:inputText>`, also note that to hide the `*` it must be set to **false** and **not** to **true**. [p:outputLabel doc](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/components/outputlabel?id=attributes) , [p:inputText doc](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/components/inputtext?id=attributes)

Answer (score -4):

```
<p:outputLabel value="Target Species" for="idInputText" />  
<p:inputText id="idInputText" required="true" value="#{controller.string}"/>
```

In your code ,you're specifically setting that label for `inputText` and this will have `asterisk`.

Remove `"for"` from `outputLabel`. It should look like :

```
 <p:outputLabel value="Target Species" />
```

Now, you won't have `asterisk` .

Comment: This resembles HTML `<label value="whatever" for="componentId" /> <input type="text" id="componentId" />`. More info: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_label.asp

Comment: The only issue with this is that the label isn't associated with the input field (ie when you click the labe text focus will not be moved to the input field). This decreases the accessibility of your webpage.

Comment: Removing the `for=""` from the label is bad advice.